# передача шаблона в шаблон с параметрами в express-handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars

Проблема следующая. шаблон "index" загружается, в переменную body передаю шаблон, но в шаблон не передаются параметры для работы handlebars шаблонизатора.
В шаблон main нужно передать переменную name. Как это сделать?

```js
var express = require('express');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', './public/views');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    body: require("./public/views/main.handlebars"),
    name: "Евгений"
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

```html
 index.handlebars


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

  {{{body}}}

</body>

</html>
```

main.handlebars

```
Тестовая страница
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

var hbs = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'index',
    layoutsDir: "./public/views",
    partialsDir: "./public/views"
});


app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', './public/views');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {


    res.render('main', {
        name: "Евгений"
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Установка шаблонизатора</h1>

    {{{body}}}
</body>
</html>
```

В {{{body}}} будет передаваться нужный шаблон, в нашем случае "main".